# Is it safe to export a NFS-mounted directory via NFS?

Tags: mount, export, nfs

Motivation: To access files on a NFS server from multiple computers without making more than one connection to the NFS server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reliability of each node aside, sure. Each VFS just forwards its requests to the next in the chain. Also, investigate the `nohide` export option.

Comment: Vaquez-Abrams I think you should update your answer to include that it's also a performance loser, BUT, it COULD also overcome some networking issues (some systems on one net, others on another and some system that's on both).  However, I am REALLY posting to say thanks for mentioning nohide as it happens to have given me a clue about something I wasn't looking for right now - thanks!